# $.post() callback not working except in one case

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Here is my problem, I've been working on it for some days and I can't get through...

In this simple code (client) :

```
$.post(req,{id:interId,idRess:idRess}, function(data){
    console.log(data);
    if(isNaN(data))
        alert(data);
    else {
            dataReload();
            closePopUp("popInter");
    }
```

The `console.log()` only works when data is `"Not working"`, I never get in the `else` either.

Server side :

```
$id = "";
if(isset($_POST['id'])){
    $id = $_POST['id'];
}
$idRess = "";
if(isset($_POST['idRess'])){
    $idRess = $_POST['idRess'];
}
if(($id != "") && ($idRess != ""))
    echo json_encode(1);
else
    echo json_encode("Not working");
```

Everything is wrapped in a try/catch, errors are handled.

The real problem is : This code works on my coworker's computer, he manages to call the functions in the `else`, the `console.log()` is working too...

I guess it is a server configuration issue, but he gave me his whole Wamp config folders and it is still the same.

What is (in your opinion) the cause(s) of this ?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: In which case `data` is supposed to be NaN?

Comment: When it gets "Not Working"
NaN => NotaNumber

not NonalphaNumeric

Comment: What do you see in the Network tab of Developer Tools?

Comment: @Barmar
gest_intervention.php?mode=add  POST  200  text/html  jquery_1_10_2.js:8706  765 B  70 ms. Everything seems fine :/

Answer (score 3):

This:

```
if(($id != "") && ($idRess != "")
```

Should be:

```
if(($id != "") && ($idRess != ""))
```

Comment: Yes, my bad, failed copy/paste

This is working on another computer.

Comment: it happens somethimes :)